# Checkbox: Check and Uncheck 5 checkbox out of 15

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am creating an android app in which I have taken 15 `Checkboxes`.

Now, I want to check 5 `Checkboxes` out of 15 `Checkboxes`.
I am doing it and I am getting 5 checkboxes after which it doesn't allow the 6th `checkbox` to be checked.

The problem I am coming through is -

When I check 5 checkboxes then it doesn't get edited. I mean if I check 2 checkboxes and then uncheck it, it holds the value. 
For eg - if i check 4 and uncheck 1, it doesn't allow me to check the 5th checkbox.

I want to resolve this problem of checking and unchecking.

my code :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

        CheckBox Veg, Nonveg, Bevarges, SoftDrink, HardDrink, FastFood,
                NorthIndian, SouthIndain, Dessert, SeaFood, Italian, Chiness,
                Maxican, Spanish, Thai;
        Button save;
        String finalresult;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayList<CheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
            Veg = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            Nonveg = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
            Bevarges = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
            SoftDrink = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
            HardDrink = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
            FastFood = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
            NorthIndian = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
            SouthIndain = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox8);
            Dessert = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox9);
            SeaFood = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox10);
            Italian = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox11);
            Chiness = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox12);
            Maxican = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox13);
            Spanish = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox14);
            Thai = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox15);
            save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();


            Veg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Veg.isChecked()) {

                        System.out.println("Veg checked");

                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            Veg.setEnabled(false);
                            Veg.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("1, ");
                            System.out.println(result.length());
                        }

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("unchecked");
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            Veg.setEnabled(false);
                            Veg.setChecked(true);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("delete");
                            if (result.length() >=15){
                                finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 3);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

            Nonveg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Nonveg.isChecked()) {

                        System.out.println("Nonveg checked");

                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);

                            Nonveg.setEnabled(false);
                            Nonveg.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("2, ");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Nonveg unchecked");

                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            Nonveg.setEnabled(false);
                            Nonveg.setChecked(true);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("nondelete");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Bevarges.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Bevarges.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);

                            Bevarges.setEnabled(false);
                            Bevarges.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("3, ");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            Bevarges.setEnabled(false);
                            Bevarges.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }

                    }
                }
            });

            SoftDrink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (SoftDrink.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);

                            SoftDrink.setEnabled(false);
                            SoftDrink.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("4, ");
                            System.out.println(result.length());
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            SoftDrink.setEnabled(false);
                            SoftDrink.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            HardDrink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (HardDrink.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            HardDrink.setEnabled(false);
                            HardDrink.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("5, ");
                            System.out.println(result.length());
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            HardDrink.setEnabled(false);
                            HardDrink.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            FastFood.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (FastFood.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            FastFood.setEnabled(false);
                            FastFood.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("6, ");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            FastFood.setEnabled(false);
                            FastFood.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            NorthIndian.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (NorthIndian.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            NorthIndian.setEnabled(false);
                            NorthIndian.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("7, ");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            NorthIndian.setEnabled(false);
                            NorthIndian.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            SouthIndain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (SouthIndain.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            SouthIndain.setEnabled(false);
                            SouthIndain.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("8, ");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            SouthIndain.setEnabled(false);
                            SouthIndain.setChecked(true);
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Dessert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Dessert.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            Dessert.setEnabled(false);
                            Dessert.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("9, ");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {

                            Dessert.setEnabled(false);
                            Dessert.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            SeaFood.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (SeaFood.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            SeaFood.setEnabled(false);
                            SeaFood.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("10,");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {

                            SeaFood.setEnabled(false);
                            SeaFood.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Italian.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Italian.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            Italian.setEnabled(false);
                            Italian.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("11,");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {

                            Italian.setEnabled(false);
                            Italian.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Chiness.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Chiness.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            Chiness.setEnabled(false);
                            Chiness.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("12,");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {

                            Chiness.setEnabled(false);
                            Chiness.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Maxican.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Maxican.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            Maxican.setEnabled(false);
                            Maxican.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("13,");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {

                            Maxican.setEnabled(false);
                            Maxican.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Spanish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Spanish.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            Spanish.setEnabled(false);
                            Spanish.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("14,");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {

                            Spanish.setEnabled(false);
                            Spanish.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            Thai.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (Thai.isChecked()) {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {
                            finalresult = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
                            Thai.setEnabled(false);
                            Thai.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            result.append("15,");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (result.length() >= 15) {

                            Thai.setEnabled(false);
                            Thai.setChecked(true);
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        Veg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);   {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String checkboxes;
            CheckBox checkbox;
            if (checkboxes.contains((CharSequence) checkbox)) {
                ((CompoundButton) checkbox).setChecked(false);
                checkboxes.remove(checkbox);
            } else {
                if (checkboxes.size() < 5) {
                    checkbox.setChecked(true);
                    checkboxes.add(checkbox);
                } else {
                    checkbox.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        }
        }); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing can you show some code so we can help?

Comment: Yes, code would be helpful. You are probably using a counter and not decrementing when unchecking.

Comment: what have you done in your code..can you show?

Comment: you should maintain the state of checkbox

Comment: This is my validated code -

Answer (score 0):

You can put the selected checkboxes into an `ArrayList<CheckBox>` and `onCheckedChangeListener` confirm that the checked `CheckBox` is on the list by using `arrayList.contains(checkedCheckbox)`.  If `true`, uncheck it. If `false` check for the `ArrayList#size()`. If it is less than 5, check it. otherwise return

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> checboxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();


// The containing class should implement OnCheckedChangeListener
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
checkbox3.....

@Override
public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton checkbox, boolean isChecked) {

   if(checkboxes.contains(checkbox)) {
       checkbox.setChecked(false);
       checkboxes.remove(checkbox);
   }
   else {
       if(checkboxes.size() < 5) {
           checkbox.setChecked(true);
           checkboxes.add(checkbox);
       } else {
           checkbox.setChecked(false);
       }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** your problem is here, this is not how you implement an interface

```
Veg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);   {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String checkboxes;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        if (checkboxes.contains((CharSequence) checkbox)) {
            ((CompoundButton) checkbox).setChecked(false);
            checkboxes.remove(checkbox);
        } else {
            if (checkboxes.size() < 5) {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
                checkboxes.add(checkbox);
            } else {
                checkbox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
    });
```

The right way to do it is:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Here goes your onCreate's code and the checkbox reference etc...

       // DO NOT set a single listener for each checkbox, instead pass "this"
       // Also, you don't need to use `setOnClickListener`
       Veg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
       Nonveg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton checkbox, boolean isChecked) {
      // Here define your logic, possibly put a similar implementation from my original answer.

      // if you NEED to implement distinct logic for each checkbox, do the following:
      switch(checkbox.getId()) {
          case R.id.checkBox1:
                // some logic
                break;
          case R.id.checkBox2:

                //..... etc
      }

 }
```

As a reminder, make sure you are **importing** `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` and not `RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: Just in case, you're not suppose to copy/paste it, but take it as a guide on how can you solve your problem. Now, what is exactly giving you error?

Comment: No, i am not doing copy/paste, but the errors are it is showing checkbox and checkboxes to define and after implementing the on checked changed listener it is again and showing to override the method. I have defined the Checkbox and Checkboxes.

Comment: is your `Activity` or `Fragment` (whichever you're using to host the `CheckBox`) implementing `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`?  If so, did you got a reference to all checkboxes you're using?   if so, did you call `setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)` on each checkbox?

Comment: I am using activity and implemented OnCheckedChangeListener. I have also defined the checkboxes as mentioned in my code mentioned above. After importing the packages it is still creating problem like define checkboxes and Checkbox...I have defined String checkboxes; and CheckBox checkbox;.

Comment: After defining these...it is showing errors in remove, size and add tags.

Comment: can you update your code with the new changes please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Simple String array:

```
ArrayList<String> str=new ArrayList<String>();
```

On checkbox change event:

```
if(isChecked) {
    if(str.size()<5) {
        str.add(ch.getText().toString());
    } else {
        ch.setChecked(false);
    }
} else {
    str.remove(ch.getText().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the user to select at max 5 options of the 15 available. If so, you can try following:

```
ArrayList<checkBox> checkBoxes; // add all your checBoxes to this Structure and set their tag as 0 to 14
ArrayList<Integer> selectedIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

class checkListener implements View.onClickListener//Set this listener to all checkboxes
{
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
{
int currIndex = v.getTag();
if(checkBoxes.get(currIndex).isChecked)
{
//already checked, just un-check it and remove it from selectedIndexes
checkBoxes.get(currIndex).setChecked(false);
selectedIndexes.remove(currIndex);
}
else
{
//The current is unChecked and wishes to be checked
if(selectedIndexes.size()<5)
{
//if no of checked elements < 5, simply check it
checkBoxes.get(currIndex).setChecked(true);
selectedIndexes.add(currIndex);
}
else
{
//or else if already 5 checked, uncheck the last checked and mark the current as checked
int lastChecked = selectedIndexes.get(selectedIndexes.size()-1);
checkBoxes.get(lastChecked).setChecked(false);
selectedIndexes.remove(lastChecked);
checkBoxes.get(currIndex).setChecked(true);
selectedIndexes.add(currIndex);
}
}
}
}
```

Finally you can iterate through the checkBoxes arrayList to get which all are checked.
Hope this bit helps you!

Comment: After implementing above code it is showing error on get(.get) used everywhere in the above code.

Comment: This is not a copy-paste-go code. Just derive the idea from this. It may have syntax errors!!